# After switching from gdm to lightdm my screen turns off when I come to the login

Tags: login, lightdm, display-manager

I tried to change my Display Manager from *gdm* to *lightdm*. After a system restart everything was normal until I got to the login place.

Instead of seeing the login screen I only heard the sound of the login appearing and the whole screen shut down. The computer was working but the screen didn't work.

I suppose the system isn't communicating with the screen and I am not sure what to do and how to make my Ubuntu work again normally because now I can't use it. I can't even log in my account before the screen turns off and this is every time.

Despite that My computer still works when I choose to start my Windows from the Boot Manager (which is the only part of Ubuntu that works without the screen turned off). Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to know exactly what is going wrong, but here are a couple easy ideas that might help:

To start off, when you can't access a GUI you can switch to a shell command prompt with Ctrl+Alt+F1, where you can log in using your user name (not display name) and password.  It then functions like Terminal would.  You can switch back to the GUI to see if it's working yet with Ctrl+Alt+F7.  So, for the course of the following possible fixes, you'll need to go into Ctrl+Alt+F1 to enter commands if you have no functioning GUI.

Do you inadvertently have both gdm and lightdm running at the same time?  To make sure you do not, use the following command:

> sudo killall gdm

Now try to restart lightdm with the following:

> sudo service lightdm restart

If you don't want to use gdm at all, you may want to enter the following to uninstall it:

> sudo apt-get remove gdm

If gdm is already uninstalled and you're having this issue, try reinstalling lightdm using:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall lightdm

You can also do this with:

> sudo apt-get remove lightdm
>
> sudo apt-get install lightdm

If you still can't see a GUI after you have tried all of the above, you may need to install the Ubuntu desktop.  To do this use:

> sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop

If it has already been installed (you will know this because the second item in the last line of that process will read "0 newly installed"), then you may want to reinstall Ubuntu desktop using:

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop

I hope at least one of those ideas works.  If at any point you wish to reboot from the Shell without having to use your power button, you'll need to switch to root and then give the command to reboot.  You'll end up doing this chain of commands:

> sudo -s
>
> reboot

Comment: When I tried to kill gdm a message saying gdm didn't existed as a process appeared. I tried to restart lightdm and it didn't work. After that I reinstalled lightdm and it also didn't work. I installed ubuntu-desktop which also didn't give any results at all. My screen still stays shut off when I switch to the user interface with Ctrl+Alt+F7.

Comment: If you install gdm again and try booting using gdm, does it work?

Comment: I installed gdm again I set it for default display manager (I had also kdm and lightdm) and rebooted. It didn't work. I removed kdm and lightdm and left only gdm. After a reboot everything was fine. Now the Display Manager works :) Thanks very much :)

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help.  :-)

Comment: And FYI--it may have also had something to do with the fact you had kdm on there, too.  Now that you've got gdm up and running, if you really wanted to try lightdm it might work if you install it again.